# Phonegap - How to generate image file from base64 string?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, base64, phonegap-plugins

Am writing a phonegap app for Android and at one point, I save a base64 PNG string as a file. However, I have observed that the string is just dumped into a file and can't be viewed as an image when opened.

I'd like to be able to save an image generated from the base64 string.This is what I have:

**The Javascript (Formated for Phonegap):**

```
/*** Saving The Pic ***/
var dataURL = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="; //A simple red dot

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile("dot.png", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
}

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {  
    fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
}

function gotFileWriter(writer) {
    writer.write(dataURL); //does not open as image
}

function fail(error) {
    console.log(error.code);
}
```

I tried editing the code to save just the image data but it did't work either. (See below)

```
function gotFileWriter(writer) {
     var justTheData = dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");//Removes everything up to ...'base64,'
     writer.write(justTheData); //also does not show
 }
```

**The HTML that triggers everthing:**

```
<p onclick="window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail)">Save a Dot</p>
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: This might be answer for this question: [stackoferflow question 11321347](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110294/nodejs-base64-image-encoding-decoding-not-quite-working)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to set the src of your image to the base 64 data to view the image.

```
var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + justTheData;
```

Comment: I am trying to save the file to disk; not to generate it for the browser. But thanks for trying, Simon.

Comment: You might need to write a plugin... I wrote a plugin for iOS that saves a canvas image to the Photo Library, you might need to do something similar. Maybe start by having a look at how images are saved in the Cordova Android Camera API?

Comment: Well you asked "I'd like to be able to view an image generated from the base64 string." so that is what I answered. You are properly writing the base64 data to file. If you load that data into an string and set the src like I mentioned it will be viewable. If you want to convert that base64 string into a binary png file you'll need to write a plugin to do it.

Comment: Solved. I created a plugin like you suggested. Thanks. [Check it out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388018/phonegap-plugin-to-convert-base64-string-to-a-png-image-in-android-solved/11388019#11388019)

Comment: can you provide the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

here no need to replace base64 string, just set convert string by following:

**in javascript:**

```
var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
image.src = justTheData;// this convert data
```

**in jquery:**

```
$("#imageid").attr("src",justTheData)
```