# Phonegap iOS-plugin to decode and store base64-encoded file strings

Tags: ios, file, cordova, plugins, base64

Hello stackoverflow community..

Currently I'm developing a Crossplatform-App (android/iOS) which generates beside its other features pdf-files from user-content.

This works well with the help of [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF).

The output of this awesome library is an base64 encoded string of the binary PDF-File.
(see this issue of the creator about the 'binaryness' of pdf files under different circumstances on [github](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/21)).

Now my actual problem:

I need to save this base64 as a proper decoded binary file for further usage on different aspects of the system (mailing it, printing it, a.s.o.).

For Android there is a Plugin that does a similar thing with [images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388018/phonegap-plugin-to-convert-base64-string-to-a-png-image-in-android?rq=1). My current plan is to modify and publish it as a more generic plugin for saving base64 encoded to a file.

Problem is now, I cannot find a similar code for iOS, and since I have literally no experience in Objective-C (plenty of Java, ruby, javascript and c though), I'm not able to produce such a plugin in short time.

Do you guys know a plugin of this kind, which can be modified with little Objective-C knowledge.

Perhaps there is someone interested in developing this kind of plugin and we cut could a deal (the project I'm working on is commercial)

Hope to hear some interesting responses, because I'm running out of ideas here :D

Greetings
Jakob

Comment: Try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11251478/896736)

Comment: Thank you, Sumanth! This looks very specific for saving/decoding images.