# Possible to download file by binary string?

Tags: android, cordova

I can download files with phonegap api. (I use cordova 2.9.1)
But only if I know the url, for example: http://domain.com/url/to/img/moo.png.

But in my server I want to read the binary data of the file and send the binary string to 
the phonegap app.

Is this possible to achieve this???

Here is the code:
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    // var uri = encodeURI("http://zielekols.com/Bilder/logo.png");

```
var uri = encodeURI('url/to/get');

fileTransfer.download(
    uri,
    '/storage/emulated/0/moo.pdf',
    function(entry) {
        console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log("download error source " + error.source);
        console.log("download error target " + error.target);
        console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
    },
    false
);
```

Comment: you mean you are getting png image in string format and want to convert in file right?

Comment: Yes. Lets say I want an image with id 5. The server reads that image as binary and sends my this data.

Comment: I think its is base64 format image string you may getting.Can you confirm this is this base64 encoding you getting?

Comment: Yes, I get base64 String.

Comment: Actually it is binary string but its no problem to convert to base64.

Comment: yes you need to decode the string and you will get byte array store to file thats it

Comment: You mean I have to send base64 String to my app?

Comment: Are you getting this kind of string? VBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==

Comment: yes but do phonegap create automatically a file?

Comment: I edited my code above

Comment: visit this link may works for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388018/phonegap-plugin-to-convert-base64-string-to-a-png-image-in-android

Comment: Yes I read that yesterday. I hoped there is an integrated solution in phonegap but seems this is not the case. Then I have to implement this plugin :-) Thank you