# Upload file to google cloud storage with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

My *upload.js* file contains the following code:

```
module.exports = {

    up: function () {
        const storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');
        const fs = require('fs');
        const gcs = storage({
            projectId: 'MY_PROJECT_ID',
            keyFilename: './service-account.json'
        });
        var bucket = gcs.bucket('MY_BUCKET');

        bucket.upload('picture.jpg', function(err, file) {
            if (err) throw new Error(err);
        });
    },
}
```

It works through the terminal but how do I call it on form submission button click or just from different file ?

When I try it gives me:

> Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

I'm quite new to *NodeJs* and I don't really know what to do.
Google documentation doesn't help me at all unfortunately :/

Comment: Are you getting this error in browser console? Or if it is a different function, can you share the code from there?

Comment: Related if there is no physical file [How do I upload a base64 encoded image (string) directly to a Google Cloud Storage bucket using Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42879012/how-do-i-upload-a-base64-encoded-image-string-directly-to-a-google-cloud-stora)

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend moving your `requires` to the first line.

```
const storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = {
    up: function () {
        const gcs = storage({
            projectId: 'MY_PROJECT_ID',
            keyFilename: './service-account.json'
        });
        const bucket = gcs.bucket('MY_BUCKET');
        bucket.upload('picture.jpg', function(err, file) {
            if (err) throw new Error(err);
        });
    },
}
```

I would also `console.log(storage)` and confirm it is defined.

Answer (score 4):

```
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');

const up = () => {
    const gcs = new Storage({
        projectId: 'xxxxxxxxx',
        keyFilename: './service-account.json'
    });
    const bucket = gcs.bucket('xxxxxxxxxx');
    bucket.upload('./test-rev.mkv', function (err, file) {
        if (err) throw new Error(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: Edit your post using code formatting, Also, consider adding any explanation to your code.