# Store a file in Firebase Storage coming from gmail attachment

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I am using Gmail api to get hold of an attachment using node as follows :

```
request({
        url: "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/xyz@gmail.com/messages/messageid/attachments/attachmentId",
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer token'
        },
        json: true
    }, function(error, response) {
        let myData = response.body.data;
        let file_data = URLSafeBase64.decode(utf8.encode(myData));
        fs.writeFileSync('path/new_file.pdf', file_data);
)};
```

And I am able to save the same locally. I need to write `file_data` to a new file and convert the same into a pdf one. I want this directly to happen in firebase storage i.e. I want to create and edit a file and change the corresponding extension as well. Is it possible ?

Comment: Did you already try any interaction with Firebase Storage? It's API is relatively straightforward and you should be able to fairly simply upload the data from the local file like for example shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48919153/upload-file-to-google-cloud-storage-with-nodejs

Comment: Actually I don't want to do `fs.writeFileSync('path/new_file.pdf', file_data);` I want to directly write to the firebase storage

Comment: There is no way to post data from a URL directly to Cloud Storage. You'll have to read it into the client first, either as a file, or as a stream. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54235721/transfer-file-from-url-to-cloud-storage