# How to upload files to Google Cloud using JavaScript only?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am wondering if it is possible to use JavaScript to upload files directly to Google Cloud without having to use Node.js or anything else. I keep searching online but all I find are tutorials with Node.js.

Comment: For objects smaller than a few hundred MB, yes, you can easily write an upload function in pure JavaScript. There are lots of examples on the Internet and StackOverflow. When objects are large (>100MB) then you need to implement multi-part uploads and that gets complicated quickly. There are some details regarding permissions that your question does not specify. While researching also search for details on signed-urls.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upload file to google cloud storage with NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48919153/upload-file-to-google-cloud-storage-with-nodejs)