# Upload JSON string to Google Cloud Storage without a file

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, google-cloud-storage, storage

My case is when I receive data from some other source as a JSON string, then I want to upload this string to Google Cloud Storage without writing this string to a local file and upload this file. Is there any way to do this. Thank you.
Look like this code below

```
storage
  .bucket(bucketName)
  .upload(jsonString, { destination: 'folder/test.json' })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('success');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error('ERROR:', err);
  });
```

so I expected the Google Cloud Storage will have a file test.json with content from the jsonString

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I upload a base64 encoded image (string) directly to a Google Cloud Storage bucket using Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42879012/how-do-i-upload-a-base64-encoded-image-string-directly-to-a-google-cloud-stora)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like this scenario has already been addressed in this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42879012/how-do-i-upload-a-base64-encoded-image-string-directly-to-a-google-cloud-stora).

Both answers look good, but it will probably be easier to use the file.save() method (second answer).You can find the description of this method and yet another example [here](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.7.x/File#save).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice. I've tried and it works. Thanks for your response

Comment: Helpful! Thank you

Comment: Can you please share some code snippet. I am unable to make it work for JSON data being extracted from an rest api.

Answer (score 4):

expanding on @ch_mike's answer

```js
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage')
const storage = new Storage()
const bucket = storage.bucket(bucketName)

const saveJsonFile = (data) => {
   const timestamp = new Date().getTime()
   const fileName = `${timestamp}.json`
   const file = bucket.file(fileName)
   const contents = JSON.stringify(data)
   return file.save(contents)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In case some one is looking for the snippet of the answer here it is using the file.save(). Please do note that the data should be stringfy.

```
const storage = new Storage();

exports.entry_point = (event, context) => {
  var data = Buffer.from(event.data, 'base64').toString();
  data = transform(data)
  var datetime = new Date().toISOString()
  var bucketName =  storage.bucket('your_filename')
  var fileName = bucketName.file(`date-${datetime}.json`)
  fileName.save(data, function(err) {
  if (!err) {
    console.log(`Successfully uploaded ${fileName}`)
  }});

  //-
  // If the callback is omitted, we'll return a Promise.
  //-
  fileName.save(data).then(function() {});
};
```