# Error here TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type object

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, firebase-admin

Hi I am trying to upload a base 64 file from NodeJs to firebase storage(google cloud storage) using the below given code. But I am getting an error stating

> Error here TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must
> be of type string. Received type object at validateString
> (internal/validators.js:125:11)

the code is:

```
const key = require('../key.json');
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
//var gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage');
exports.uploadVideo = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

    const gcs =new Storage({
        projectId: "<my-project-id>",
        keyFilename: key
      });

      const bucket = gcs.bucket("example.appspot.com");
      const gcsname = 'test.pdf';
      const file = bucket.file(gcsname);
      var pdfdata = "xNC9YUmVmU3RtIDE1NzQ+Pg0Kc3RhcnR4cmVmDQoyMTY5DQolJUVPRg==";
      var buff = Buffer.from(pdfdata, 'binary').toString('utf-8');
      const stream = file.createWriteStream({
        metadata: {
          contentType: 'application/pdf'
        }
      });

      stream.on('error', (err) => {
        console.log("Error here",err);
      });
      stream.on('finish', () => {
        console.log(gcsname);
      });
      stream.end(new Buffer.from(buff, 'base64'));})
```

Can someone suggest me a way out? I can't understand the problem.
Thanks

Comment: can you provide your package.json file?

Comment: @google-cloud/storage is installed. If you want to look for something else I can post it.

Comment: @waseemTahir did you figure this out? I am having the same issue...

Comment: @Lion789 No, sadly I couldn't and I had a tight deadline so I implemented that on frontend itself without wasting my time further.

Comment: Thanks for the response, yeah I just ignored using winston with gcloud

Answer (score 0):

It means that the program is expecting the `path` argument to of be type `string`, example: `"path/to/whatever"`. And you're giving it an object - example: `{ path: "path/to/whatever" }`

Comment: That's what error is saying itself. But according to the docs it should be done this way. also I'm not giving any path, that's being extracted by an internal google library itself, probably from file object.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the docs you're referring to?

Comment: Have you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42879012/how-do-i-upload-a-base64-encoded-image-string-directly-to-a-google-cloud-stora. I think the accepted answer here is what you're looking for

Comment: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-node/issues/2334 this is the source which I thought would work for me, but no success so far. Also this isn't an official doc. Couldn't find any official docs for my required usecase.

Comment: Ok. Compared your code line by line with the Github example your provided. The last line seems to be different. Yours should be changed to `stream.end(new Buffer(buff, 'base64'));`

Comment: Nvm..I see why you did that.. https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_new_buffer_string_encoding

Comment: Buffer is deprecated so Buffer.from was used instead.

Comment: How about this `stream.end(Buffer.from(buff, 'base64'));})`?

Comment: hmm...May be try the `file.save` api instead - https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#save. Example here as well - https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-node/issues/2334#issuecomment-607828801

Comment: Yeah used that too. Didn't work for me. It might be due to some incompatible libraries. I guess this will remain a mystery forever. I'll look for an alternative technique for this. Thanks for giving your time to this. I guess it's time to move on.

Answer (score 0):

As the error said "TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined"

It trying to grab from path, which you should add those variables into your .env file to the root when looking for path ..it will grab the right variables. Let me know if you still have difficulties..

You can refer to [Express Routing with Google Cloud Functions](https://medium.com/google-cloud/express-routing-with-google-cloud-functions-36fb55885c68) for more details informations.

Answer (score -1):

This will be fixed if you are using "react-scripts" "^3.x.x" replace it to "^3.4.1" version or latest one.
Please make sure you deleted the node_modules folder before npm/yarn install